# Take the result of a method and populate a constructor

Tags: javascript

I want to take the results of the "addResults" method and populate constructors "this.latitude" and "this.longitude" with the results. Is this possible?

```
class Weather {

    constructor(latitude, longitude) {

        this.latitude = latitude
        this.longitude = longitude;
    }
    // fetch weather from API
    async getWeather() {
        const response = await fetch(`https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://api.darksky.net/forecast/fe1ff29d5df09ef94625244329e7b5e4/${this.latitude},${this.longitude}`);

        const responseData = await response.json();

        return responseData;
    }

    // Change weather location
    changeLocation(city, state) {
        this.city = city;
        this.state = state;
    }

    addResults(results) {
        this.results = results;
    }
}
```

Comment: add results comes from a function in my app.js file. It fetches, from another API, the latitude and longitude of a location, that the user enters, that can then be placed in the Dark Sky weather api fetch.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you will be calling `getResults()` somewhere you can do (as a rudimentary example):

```
const results = getResults();
this.latitude = results.latitude;
this.longitude = results.longitude;
```

You can assign and reassign the values of any instance variables.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Sorry I am a javascript newbie and still cant seem to make this work. I have added a getResults() function, but still cant get the this.latitude and this.longitude to reassign to the new variables.